# Chart.js (CodeIgniter) doesnt display data

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, chart.js

I already query and json displays the data in Inspect Element>Network>Preview
then I'm fetching it on my js code.

Here wherein the data will be fetch

```
"dataSrc": function (jsn) {
            fill_pie([jsn.all_acc, jsn.recordsFiltered], ['All Accounts', 'Verified Accounts']);
            return jsn.data;
        }
```

and here will the data will display

```
function fill_pie(varData = [0], varLabel = ['No Data']) {
    if (filterClick == 1) {

        if (myChart) {
            myChart.destroy();
        }

        var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");

        myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: varLabel,
                datasets: [{
                    data: varData,
                    backgroundColor: ["#83827E", "#00C851",],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: "Real Property Tax Account" 
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            userCallback: function (label, index, labels) {
                                // when the floored value is the same as the value we have a whole number
                                if (Math.floor(label) === label) {
                                    return label;
                                }

                            },
                        }
                    }],
                },
            }
        });
        filterClick = 0;
    }
}

fill_pie();

})
```

It displays "No data" and no error in network. What would be the problem? What should I do?

Comment: What is the call to fill_pie() with no data in the last line for?

Comment: I removed it and it works. Thanks mate!

Comment: please remove as simple typographical error. unlikely to help others.